# Placements of \RequirePackage \documentclass \usepackage

Tags: packages

Want to understand how the placements of `\RequirePackage`, `\documentclass`, and `\usepackage` should be made.

In my style files I use `\RequirePackage`.  In my document I call with the following sequence.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mystyle}
```

Have seen that `\usepackage` cannot be put before `\documentclass`, but `\RequirePackage`.  When is there a requirement for `\RequirePackage` to precede `\documentclass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For historical reasons, a few packages should be loaded before `\documentclass`, but the main one is `fix-cm` (if you need it). With some proprietary document classes, you *might* need to load a couple of packages before `\documentclass`, but it's quite an unusual situation.

For such packages you have to resort to `\RequirePackage`.

For those you load after `\documentclass` *always* do `\usepackage`.

Comment: Thanks for the detail.  From what you outlines, the standard practice is to call packages  with `\usepackage`.  Has been said to me that style files use `\RequirePackage` rather than `\usepackage` even though they themselves are called after `\documentclass` and with `\usepackage{mystyle}`.

Comment: @konmi Yes, it's recommended to use `\RequirePackage` in `.sty` files. The fact that after `\documentclass` the two are presently the same command should not be taken into account (the two commands might become different in future releases of LaTeX, one never knows).

Comment: Was going to ask what different functionality they provide, but you explained at being the same command.